# Differentiate active language between Simplified and Traditional Chinese

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, internationalization, chinese-locale

Is there a way to differentiate between traditional and simplified chinese language without delving into country codes.

Using this …

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode]
```

… the language code for both is `zh`.

Is there a good way to query if the current language or locale is zh-HANS or zh-HANZ, without further distinction by country (*zh_TW*, *zh_CN*, etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this: used `NSLocal.preferredLanguages`. Get array first one, it can be `zh-Hant` or `zh-Hants`.

```
func getCurrentLanguage() -> String {
   let languages = NSLocale.preferredLanguages()
   let currentLanguage = languages[0] as? String
   return currentLanguage ?? ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite Zhengjie's answer in Swift 4:

```
func getCurrentLanguage() -> String {
    let languages = NSLocale.preferredLanguages
    let currentLanguage = languages[0]
    return currentLanguage
}
```